# Prove one property of harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u(x)$ be a harmonic function defined in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Suppose that $u(x_k)=0$, where $x_k=(1/k,1/k).$ Prove that $u(x)=0$ everywhere in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Won't the $u(x, y) = x - y$ be the counterexample?

Comment: Thanks. you are right. This statement is wrong.